# How to securely perfom form based authentication in Java?

Tags: java

Using this link  http://www.elitejavacoder.com/2013/10/http-client-form-based-authentication.html I adapted the code to my needs.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try{            

        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, protocol);

        client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, httpHost);

        HttpGet securedResource = new HttpGet("/login?from=");            
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

        System.out.println("Http status code for Unauthenticated Request: " + statusCode);// Statue code should be 200
        System.out.println("Response for Unauthenticated Request: \n" + strResponse); // Should be login page
        System.out.println("================================================================\n");


        HttpPost authpost = new HttpPost("/j_acegi_security_check");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "timotei"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "timotei"));

        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Submit", "log in"));


        authpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8);
        authpost.setEntity(entity);

        httpResponse = client.execute(authpost);
        responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

        System.out.println("Http status code for Authenticattion Request: " + statusCode);// Status code should be 302
        System.out.println("Response for Authenticattion Request: \n" + strResponse); // Should be blank string
        System.out.println("================================================================\n");

        httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);
        responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

        System.out.println("Http status code for Authenticated Request: " + statusCode);// Status code should be 200
        System.out.println("Response for Authenticated Request: \n" + strResponse);// Should be actual page
        System.out.println("================================================================\n");


        HttpPost buildPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/job/Item/buildWithParameters?build=true");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(buildPost);

        System.out.println("Build response: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can't figure out how to send the username and password in a secured manner. My server isn't https configured.

In principle I'm looking for a path to solving this, if there is anyone who has some ideas/documentation links please answer to this question.

**EDIT:** I want to avoid server side decryption since I don't own the server.

Comment: Look a salting technique. : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Since the server obviously expects the password in plain text, I strongly suggest to enable HTTPS. I also can't think of another transparent way to transport the password securely. Everything else would require changes on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I looked on Digest authentication and I have now the following code:

```
        URL url;
  try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");

        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(),url.getProtocol());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
        authCache.put(targetHost, digestScheme);

        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        context.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpPost post= new HttpPost("post to url");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        //    }

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url.getPath());


        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpget, context);
        System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It seems Digest authentication is done by hashing the password with MD5.

Is this a secured method ? (a drawback to my problem)

Comment: Hi John, Stackoverflow does not work like a traditional discussion board. You ask a question and get answers. Users can request clarifications in the comments or discuss in the chat. Please either update your original question or post a new one. That being said, does your server support digest authentication? If so, make sure it also supports a secure hash algorithm (MD5 does NOT count as secure anymore) and you should be fine.